# Why doesn't Python process with input and output queues not join once it is done?

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing

This simple Python3 program using `multiprocessing` does not seem to work as expected.

All the input processes share an input queue from which they consume data. They all share an output queue where they write a result once they are fully done. I find that this program hangs at the process `join()`. Why is that?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import multiprocessing

def worker_func(in_q, out_q):
    print("A worker has started")    
    w_results = {}
    while not in_q.empty():
        v = in_q.get()
        w_results[v] = v
    out_q.put(w_results)
    print("A worker has finished")

def main():

    # Input queue to share among processes
    fpaths = [str(i) for i in range(10000)]
    in_q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for fpath in fpaths:
        in_q.put(fpath)

    # Create processes and start them
    N_PROC = 2
    out_q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    workers = []
    for _ in range(N_PROC):
        w = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_func, args=(in_q, out_q,))
        w.start()
        workers.append(w)
    print("Done adding workers")

    # Wait for processes to finish
    for w in workers:
        w.join()
    print("Done join of workers")

    # Collate worker results
    out_results = {}
    while not out_q.empty():
        out_results.update(out_q.get())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get this result from this program when `N_PROC = 2`:

```
$ python3 test.py
Done adding workers
A worker has started
A worker has started
A worker has finished
<---- I do not get "A worker has finished" from second worker
<---- I do not get "Done join of workers"
```

It does not work even with a single child process `N_PROC = 1`:

```
$ python3 test.py
Done adding workers
A worker has started
A worker has finished
<---- I do not get "Done join of workers"
```

If I try a smaller input queue with say 1000 items, everything works fine.

I am aware of some old StackOverflow questions that say that the Queue has a limit. Why is this not documented in the Python3 docs?

What is an alternative solution I can use? I want to use multi-processing (not threading), to split the input among N processes. Once their shared input queue is empty, I want each process to collect its results (can be a big/complex data structure like dict) and return it back to the parent process. How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classical bug caused by your design. When the worker are terminating, they stall because they have not been able to put all the data in the `out_q`, thus deadlocking your program. This has to do with size of the pipe buffer underlying your queue.

When you are using a `multiprocessing.Queue`, you should empty it before trying to join the feeder process, to make sure that the `Process` does not stall waiting for all the object to be put in the `Queue`. So putting your `out_q.get` call before the joinning the processes should solve your problem:. You can use a sentinel pattern to detect the end of the computations.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing.queues import Empty

def worker_func(in_q, out_q):
    print("A worker has started")    
    w_results = {}
    while not in_q.empty():
        try:
            v = in_q.get(timeout=1)
            w_results[v] = v
        except Empty:
            pass
    out_q.put(w_results)
    out_q.put(None)
    print("A worker has finished")

def main():

    # Input queue to share among processes
    fpaths = [str(i) for i in range(10000)]
    in_q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    for fpath in fpaths:
        in_q.put(fpath)

    # Create processes and start them
    N_PROC = 2
    out_q = multiprocessing.Queue()
    workers = []
    for _ in range(N_PROC):
        w = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker_func, args=(in_q, out_q,))
        w.start()
        workers.append(w)
    print("Done adding workers")

    # Collate worker results
    out_results = {}
    n_proc_end = 0
    while not n_proc_end == N_PROC:
        res = out_q.get()
        if res is None:
            n_proc_end += 1
        else:
            out_results.update(res)

    # Wait for processes to finish
    for w in workers:
        w.join()
    print("Done join of workers")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also, note that your code has a race condition in it. The queue `in_q` can be emptied between the moment you check `not in_q.empty()` and the `get`. You should use a non blocking get to make sure you don't deadlock, waiting on an empty queue.

Finally, you are trying to implement something that look like a `multiprocessing.Pool`, which handle this kind of communication in a more robust way. you can also look at the [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) API, which is even more robust and in some sense, better designed.